# following linq performing left outer join instead of inner join

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, inner-join

I cannot see where the problem lies with the following code. I am trying to retrieve those employees who are named as responsibles for certain vacancie. I have about 20 vacancies in my DB assigned to some 16 employees and about 1801 employee records in the employees table. The code always returns a result with 1801 entries.

```
from emp in container.Employees
join p in container.Vacancies
on emp.EMPID equals p.ResponsibleOfficer into j
group j by new {k1=emp.EMPID,k2=emp.NAME} into g
select new { EmpId = g.Key.k1, Name = g.Key.k2 , Count = g.Count()}
```

I want something similar to this

```
select emp.EmpId,emp.Name,Count(*) as count
from Vacancies p, Employees e
where p.ResponsibleOfficer=e.EmpId
group by e.EmpId,e.Name
```

any help is much appreciated. thanks

Comment: Please pay attention to the preview when you're posting a question, and try to format your post nicely. I've edited the query to avoid the unfortunate indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `join ... into`. That will *always* return a single result for each element of the original sequence, even if there are no matches in the right sequence.

You can filter out entries with no elements in `j` using a `where` clause:

```
from emp in container.Employees
join p in container.Vacancies
on emp.EMPID equals p.ResponsibleOfficer into j
where j.Any()
group j by new {k1=emp.EMPID,k2=emp.NAME} into g
select new { EmpId = g.Key.k1, Name = g.Key.k2 , Count = g.Count()}
```

Or you could just use an inner join to start with - but I don't understand your current grouping well enough to see what you're trying to do. What *is* your `group by` clause for?

EDIT: If it was really just to group by employee, you're already doing that. You can change the code to:

```
from emp in container.Employees
join p in container.Vacancies
on emp.EMPID equals p.ResponsibleOfficer into j
where j.Any()
select new { Employee = emp, Count = j.Count()}
```

Basically, after the `join` you've got two range variables in scope: `emp` (the "current" employee) and `j` (all the relevant vacancies matching that employee). You're just trying to count `j` for each employee, right?

Comment: ok, maybe i do not understand linq well enough. i am using group by to group my result by EMPID and NAME so i can count the vacancies for each of the combination, or so i think i am doing. can you please explain why it's wrong and how an inner join could be written? thanks. I will mark the question answered tomorrow once in the office, can't test this on linux at home.

Comment: @kfc: What "combination" do you mean? Aren't you really just grouping by employee, ultimately? In which case you don't need the `group by` at all. I'll edit for that...

Comment: great. exactly what i needed. I will need to read more about linq. I assumed i had to group by by myself. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using lambda, but works:

```
container
    .Employees
    .Join(container.Vacancies, l => l.EmpId, e => e.ResponsibleOfficer, (l, e) => new { l.EmpId, l.Name })
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.EmpId, g.Name })
    .Select(s => new { EmpId = s.Key.EmpId, Name = s.Key.Name, Count = s.Count() });
```